# Calculate rank by group

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

I have a data frame with a grouping variable 'ID' and some values ('Value'):

```
dt <- data.frame(
        ID = c('A1','A2','A4','A2','A1','A4','A3','A2','A1','A3'),
        Value = c(4,3,1,3,4,6,6,1,8,4)
    )
dt
#    ID Value
# 1  A1     4
# 2  A2     3
# 3  A4     1
# 4  A2     3
# 5  A1     4
# 6  A4     6
# 7  A3     6
# 8  A2     1
# 9  A1     8
# 10 A3     4
```

I can calculate an overall rank order of the 'Value' column like this:

```
dt$Order <- rank(dt$Value, ties.method = "first")
dt
#    ID Value Order
# 1  A1     4     5
# 2  A2     3     3
# 3  A4     1     1
# 4  A2     3     4
# 5  A1     4     6
# 6  A4     6     8
# 7  A3     6     9
# 8  A2     1     2
# 9  A1     8    10
# 10 A3     4     7
```

But how can I calculate rank order within each 'ID', instead of a global rank order?

```
#    ID Value  rnk
# 1  A1     4    1
# 2  A2     3    2
# 3  A4     1    1
# 4  A2     3    3
# 5  A1     4    2
# 6  A4     6    2
# 7  A3     6    2
# 8  A2     1    1
# 9  A1     8    3
# 10 A3     4    1
```

In T-SQL, we can get this done as the following syntax:

```
RANK() OVER ( [ < partition_by_clause > ] < order_by_clause > )
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My way but there's likely better.  Never used rank, din't even know about it.  Thanks, may be useful.

```
#Your Data
dt <- data.frame(
    ID = c('A1','A2','A4','A2','A1','A4','A3','A2','A1','A3'),
    Value = c(4,3,1,3,4,6,6,1,8,4)
)
dt$Order <- rank(dt$Value,ties.method= "first")

#My approach
dt$id <- 1:nrow(dt) #needed for ordering and putting things back together
dt <- dt[order(dt$ID),]
dt$Order.by.group <- unlist(with(dt, tapply(Value, ID, function(x) rank(x, 
    ties.method = "first"))))
dt[order(dt$id), -4]
```

Yields:

```
   ID Value Order Order.by.group
1  A1     4     5              1
2  A2     3     3              2
3  A4     1     1              1
4  A2     3     4              3
5  A1     4     6              2
6  A4     6     8              2
7  A3     6     9              2
8  A2     1     2              1
9  A1     8    10              3
10 A3     4     7              1
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't care about preserving the original order of the data then this works with less code:

```
dt <- dt[order(dt$ID),]
dt$Order.by.group <- unlist(with(dt, tapply(Value, ID, function(x) rank(x, 
   ties.method= "first"))))

   ID Value Order.by.group
1  A1     4              1
5  A1     4              2
9  A1     8              3
2  A2     3              2
4  A2     3              3
8  A2     1              1
7  A3     6              2
10 A3     4              1
3  A4     1              1
6  A4     6              2
```

Answer (score 14):

Many options.

If performance is an issue (i.e. very large data), use the **data.table** package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
# or: dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt[ , Order := frank(Value, ties.method = "first"), by = ID]

#          ID Value Order
#      <char> <num> <int>
#  1:     A1     4     1
#  2:     A2     3     2
#  3:     A4     1     1
#  4:     A2     3     3
#  5:     A1     4     2
#  6:     A4     6     2
#  7:     A3     6     2
#  8:     A2     1     1
#  9:     A1     8     3
# 10:     A3     4     1
```

See `?frank` for several other ties methods, e.g. `"dense"`

---

`dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(rnk = row_number(Value))
```

From `?ranking`:

> `row_number()`: equivalent to `rank(ties.method = "first")`

`dplyr` has several other ranking functions, e.g. `dense_rank`

---

Or in all its gory detail, a `base` R solution using `split`, `lapply`, `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dt, dt$ID), transform,
              Order = rank(Value, ties.method = "first")))
```

---

Using `ddply` from the **plyr** package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dt, .(ID), transform, Order = rank(Value, ties.method = "first"))
   ID Value Order
1  A1     4     1
2  A1     4     2
3  A1     8     3
4  A2     3     2
5  A2     3     3
6  A2     1     1
7  A3     6     2
8  A3     4     1
9  A4     1     1
10 A4     6     2
```

---

See revision history for `data.table` alternatives for older package versions.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of approaches:

**ave**  This takes each set of Value numbers that have the same ID and applies rank separately to each such set.  No packages are used.

```
Rank <- function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")
transform(dt, rank = ave(Value, ID, FUN = Rank))
```

giving:

```
   ID Value rank
1  A1     4    1
2  A2     3    2
3  A4     1    1
4  A2     3    3
5  A1     4    2
6  A4     6    2
7  A3     6    2
8  A2     1    1
9  A1     8    3
10 A3     4    1
```

Note that the above solution keeps the original row order.  It could be sorted afterwards if that were desired.

**sqldf with RPostgreSQL**

```
# see FAQ #12 on the sqldf github home page for info on sqldf and PostgreSQL
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html

library(RPostgreSQL)
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select 
          *, 
          rank() over (partition by "ID" order by "Value") rank 
       from "dt"
')
```

This solution reorders the rows.  It is assumed that that is ok since your example solution did that (but if not append a sequence number column to `dt` and add an appropriate order by clause to re-order the result back into the sequence number order).

Comment: I know this was from long ago, but could you elaborate on your first method? It appears to be giving me a rank of one for every entry in my table. I only have the column I want to group by second and the column I want to rank in the first argument as you have here.

Comment: I have added some explanation and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data.table package.

`setDT(dt)
dt[, Order := rank(Value, ties.method = "first"), by = "ID"]
dt <- as.data.frame(dt)`

giving the desired output:

```
   ID Value Order
1  A1     4     1
2  A2     3     2
3  A4     1     1
4  A2     3     3
5  A1     4     2
6  A4     6     2
7  A3     6     2
8  A2     1     1
9  A1     8     3
10 A3     4     1
```