# How to find the nth lowest value without sorting

Tags: r

I have a data set with values for multiple cities in each state. I would like to get the third (for example) lowest value in each state, and also return the name of the city.

I can get the lowest value in each state with:

```
tapply(df2[,11],df2$State, min )
```

But how do I get the nth lowest (and also return the city name)?

Data is in column 11, state is in column 7 (with the header "State"), city name is in column 2.

Comment: Rank by group, then subset any rank==3, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961700/how-to-partition-when-ranking-on-a-particular-column

Comment: partial sorting? `sort(x, partial=n)[n]`?

Comment: @Arun partial sounds interesting, could you provide answer using my dummy data below? Can't get my head around it... Group by State and get nth lowest?

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
#Dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  State=paste0("State",sort(rep(1:2,10))),
  City=rep(paste0("city",rep(1:10,2))),
  Value=runif(n=20))

#get rank per State
df$Rank <- ave(df$Value, df$State, FUN = rank)

#subset 3rd lowest per State
df[df$Rank==3,]
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Arun, partial sort solution, using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[dt[, .I[Value == sort(Value, partial=3L)[3L]], by=State]$V1]
```

Comment: Using `data.table`, I was thinking something like: `DT[DT[, .I[Value == sort(Value, partial=3L)[3L]], by=State]$V1]`

Comment: Of course to take care of floating point comparison, you could do: `abs(Value - sort(Value, partial=3L)[3L]) < 1e-20)` instead of `==`..

Comment: The point is that `rank` has to `sort` through all the values anyways. So, using it wouldn't answer this question.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but to take the first occurrence in the case of a tie: df$Rank <- ave(df$Value, df$State, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method="first"))

Comment: @user3637776 Yes, that is correct. But as Arun pointed out, using rank will do the sorting for the full data, use `data.table` solution for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dummy data created by @zx8754, you could also use `dplyr`'s `nth` function:

```
require(dplyr)    

df %.% group_by(State) %.% arrange(Value) %.% filter(Value == nth(Value, 3))

#   State   City     Value
#1 State1  city4 0.2672206
#2 State2 city10 0.4281415
```

Note: this method sorts the (entire) data by group, so if you really need a method without sorting, this doesn't apply (but it gets you the 3rd lowest Value per State).

Answer (score -2):

Keep track of the lowest, the second lowest, and the third lowest in variables. Whenever you see a new lowest value, put the previous lowest in the second lowest variable, and put the current second lowest in the third lowest variable.

Comment: not entirely true. Your value won't necessarily be at the end of the queue. In a queue you place items at the front of the queue. If you were looking for the 2nd smallest, and your list was 2 1 3, you place 3 on the queue (3), you then take 1 and place it (1 3), now you pop 3 and place 2 (2 1). In this case you can see that your statement of end of the queue is wrong