# R Sequence Generation For a subset

Tags: r, seq

I have requirement for sequence generation in R, but it needs to be unique in combination with another field.
For example, my data:

```
GrpID   Data   NewSeqId
100     683      1
100     534      2 
100     234      3
200     456      1
200     23       2
200     634      3
```

So my data contains GrpID and Data, i need the NewSeqID generated as per the above shown pattern. It should start from 1 for every unique GrpID. Any ideas on how to get this done in R??

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961700/how-to-partition-when-ranking-on-a-particular-column) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame).

Comment: @zx8754 it doesn't look like a ranking problem, rather a simple sequence per group.